# Add a date range column to Queryset

Tags: python, django

Django newbie, thanks in advance for any help.

I want to add a field that includes a date range for a grouping. The date range would look like "1/1/2018 to 1/2/2018" where the first date is the minimum date and the second is the maximum date in the set for a particular name.

```
qs = Qs.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs) \
       .values('name')
       .annotate(v1 = Sum('something')
               , DATE_RANGE = Min('date') + ' - ' + Max('date'))
       .order_by()
```

The end goal is to be able to display this in the template.

Comment: The closer I could get: `Qs.objects.all().annotate(date_range=Concat(Qs.objects.all().aggregate(Max('date')), Value(' to '), Qs.objects.all().aggregate(Min('date'))))`, but it's not working

Comment: @gogaz, although that didn't work, that example spiraled me into an actual solution.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Post your solution as answer if you think it could help other people (I am, myself, a bit curious about the solution you found)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Example.objects.filter(date__range=["2018-01-01", "2011-02-01"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I must not have been clear with my question, apologies.  Here is what I ended up going with. Again, the goal is to a add a column to the query set which is a concatenation of the minimum date and maximum date.

```
Name  |  Min Date  |  Max Date  | NEW COLUMN              
Dan   |  1-1-2011  |  2-2-2022  | 1-1-2011 to 2-2-2022
Sam   |  1-2-2011  |  3-12-2022 | 1-2-2011 to 3-12-2022



def someview(request):

    qs = Qs.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs) \
                   .values('Name') \
                   .annotate(temp_min_date = Min(date)
                            ,temp_max_date = Max(date)) \
                   .order_by()

    for o in qs:
      o['date_range'] = "{0} to {1}".format(o['temp_min_date'], o['temp_max_date'])
```